# ProcessBuilder not working with Processing

Tags: java, git, operating-system, processing

I am working on creating a sketch with Processing, and I would like to add the version number to it. I'm trying to run the following:

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("git", "describe", "--tags");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = br.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        System.out.println(line);
        version = line;
    }
    // Close buffer reader
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I always get a blank response. If I run the command on the terminal I get the version number. What could be the reason for the above to get only a blank response?

My thinking is that probably processing is running on its separate directory, rather than running directly where the sketch is located. If so, how could I make the code above run at the sketch location?

Comment: You’re probably seeing the last line of an error message, which happens to be a blank line.  After you close the BufferedReader, check whether `p.waitFor()` returns zero.  If the return code is not zero, the command failed.

Comment: It is returning zero. I do believe the issue is that when calling processing to run the sketch, processing runs it .exe instance on the installation folder. Thus, when calling the command there are no git instances at that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Processing does not necessarily run at the location of the sketch. Thus, when running the `git describe --tags` from the ProcessBuilder, the command ran at the location of `processing.exe`.

A simple solution was to set the directory of ProcessBuilder like this:

```
 pb.directory(new File(sketchPath())); // Run at sketch directory
```